# how to add custom font families in typography of grapes js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, grapesjs

In grape.js library, on load, how to add custom font families in the typography. I'm trying but cannot find a way to add custom fonts. Anyone who add custom font families?

Comment: See this Github issue: https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/issues/857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do so is to add it via the initialization object. Don't specify any font family I just update its name.

```
buildProps: ['font-family', ...],
properties:[
    { name: 'Font', property: 'font-family'},
    ...
```

Default fonts are taken from its PropertyFactory so if you want to add others you have to declare them all on init.

```
buildProps: ['font-family', ...],
properties:[
    {  
        property: 'font-family',
        name: 'Font',
        list: [
            { name: 'Arial', value: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' }
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
```